# ejabberd failed compilation with Elixir

Tags: elixir, ejabberd

I'm very new to Elixir and am trying to set up ejabberd using the instructions on the page https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/elixir/ (I'm on Erlang/OTP 19 and Elixir 1.3.2).

When doing `mix compile`, I get a very long screen output which terminated in a compilation error:

...

```
                                                {line,1239}]},
                                              {lager_transform,walk_ast,2,
                                               [{file,
                                                 "/media/common/code/elixir/ejapp/deps/lager/src/lager_transform.erl"},
                                                {line,62}]},
                                              {compile,
                                               '-foldl_transform/2-anonymous-2-',
                                               2,
                                               [{file,"compile.erl"},
                                                {line,958}]},
                                              {compile,foldl_transform,2,
                                               [{file,"compile.erl"},
                                                {line,960}]},
                                              {compile,
                                               '-internal_comp/4-anonymous-1-',
                                               2,
                                               [{file,"compile.erl"},
                                                {line,315}]},
                                              {compile,fold_comp,3,
                                               [{file,"compile.erl"},
                                                {line,341}]},
                                              {compile,internal_comp,4,
                                               [{file,"compile.erl"},
                                                {line,325}]},
                                              {compile,
                                               '-do_compile/2-anonymous-0-',2,
                                               [{file,"compile.erl"},
                                                {line,175}]}]}
could not compile dependency :ejabberd, "mix compile" failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile ejabberd", update it with "mix deps.update ejabberd" or clean it with "mix deps.clean ejabberd"
==> ejapp
** (Mix) Encountered compilation errors
```

I have no idea what's wrong and how to fix it. It looks like there's some problem with something called `lager` but I don't know how to fix it. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out ejabberd is not ready for Erlang 19 yet. Some of its dependencies seem to still live in the OTP 18 world. So I downgraded Erlang to 18, and Elixir to 1.2.6 and now it compiled fine.